# Check whether cygwin is installed & install if needed

Tags: java, deployment, installation, cygwin

I am trying to run shell scripts in Windows XP using Java. I found that we can run shell scripts using **cygwin** in Windows, but what if it is not installed on the system?

I want to check whether it is installed on machine, if it is not installed - add that software as a part of my application and install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cygwin complains with windows installer standards then when you install it you should be able to find a registry entry for this program.

You should check the registry for something like localmachine/software/cygwin.... this validation can be done using RegistryKey class in c#.

To include this program as a dependency you must provide the way you are installing your app,  visual studio windows installer? Inno installer?

Comment: It's `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cygwin`.  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup` points to the Cygwin root directory (typically `C:\cygwin`).